# MySQL group calculation ignoring 0 status group

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to get sum of a column of a group (**marks**), according to another column (**is_goodDegree**) only contains value **1**. and with group by **san** and **temp_key**

Check below image;

[image]

It should calculate group 2 marks (45+43+47) while it should ignore Group 1.

How can I write a SQL query for this? please advise.

Comment: Hint:  `WHERE` for filtering the rows.

Comment: select *,sum(marks) from table_name where is_goodDegree =1 group by san

Comment: Actually I think he wants to exclude groups that has `goodDegree = 0` @GordonLinoff

Comment: @sagi i want to get sum of marks where only all  'is_goodDegree' = 1 groups

Comment: That's exactly what I said . @LST

Comment: you have is_goodDegree value 0 on id 302 so don't need to group those id 301,302,303 is it ?

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: i think this is is what you need exactly select *,sum(marks) as marks from your_table 
where san not in (select san from your_table where is_goodDegree=0 ) 
group by san,temp_key;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `HAVING` clause :

```
SELECT t.san,SUM(t.marks) as sum_marks
FROM YourTable t
GROUP BY t.san
HAVING MIN(t.is_goodDegree) = 1
```

Comment: i want to get sum of marks where only all  'is_goodDegree' = 1 groups

Comment: Yea, and that's what it does. It checks that the minimum `is_goodDegree` of each group is 1, which means `0` doesn't exists . @LST Did you even try it?

Comment: Yes i checked it thanks , but on a group, 'is_goodDegree' column of each row should be 1. like row id (304, 305, 306) should give sum , while row (301, 302, 303) shouldn't, cos row 303 is_goodDegree is 0

Comment: I don't understand the problem.. and?!

Comment: I think this answers the question.

Answer (score 1):

As per your question i think this is what you need exactly

```
select *,sum(marks) as marks 
from your_table 
where san not in (select san from your_table where is_goodDegree=0 ) 
group by san,temp_key;
```